# Does anyone recognize these polynomials? Need to compute a riemann lebesgue type limit

Tags: polynomials, fourier-analysis, limits-and-convergence

These polynomials show up naturally in my work
$$
p_n(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j} \frac{(-x)^j}{j!}
$$
Does anyone know recognize if they belong to any class of well known polynomials. I am trying to compute
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{R^2}  f(|r|)e^{-\frac{a}{2}|x|^2} p_n(a x) \, dx
$$
for some nice function f and $a > 0$. I think the limit should be 0.

Comment: Check the integral there, it doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maple says $$\sum _{j=0}^{n}{\frac {{n\choose j} \left( -z \right) ^{j}}{j!}}={L}_n \left(z \right)$$ Laguerre polynomials.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials and go down to "closed form".